# ValidationMessageFor customValidatioMessage parameter, Message is always displayed, unobtrusive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, message, unobtrusive-validation, customvalidator, radiobuttonfor

Im trying to us the 
`Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.MyProperty,"The field is very much required");`

However.. Im alos using unobtrusive for my validations, but for some reason it seems like once Im using the customValidationMessage parameter, the unobtrusive validation for that property "breaks".

Or to put it in more simple terms... the validation message is always displayed, no matter if I enter a value or not.. it simply doesnt update/toggle.

The property is also used on a RadioButtonFor.. so the full "code" is:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Myproperty,"Value 1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Myproperty,"Value 2")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.MyProperty,"Please select ine of the options")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you included these jquery libraries?

```
jquery-1.9.2.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

If already, add this css style in page.

```
.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}
.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: the css wasnt added, ty